# TFS 2013 Add-in for word 2013

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

My company uses TFS 2013, Visual Studio 2013 and word 2013.

Anybody knows any add-in for word? I used to use AIT Add-in, but they don't have update for this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- [TeamSystemSolutions TeamSpec](http://www.teamsystemsolutions.com/teamspec/features/microsoft-word-integration.aspx)

When you install Team Explorer 2012 or just the [TFS Client Object Model 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f30e5cc7-036e-449c-a541-d522299445aa) to your machine, you should be able to use the following tools as well against TFS 2013:

- [Microsoft ALM Rangers' Word4TFS](http://vsarword4tfs.codeplex.com/)
- [AIT WordToTFS](http://www.aitgmbh.de/index.php?id=222)